# Asterisk - Video Recording on current version (18.6.0)

Tags: video, recording, asterisk

I’ve setup Asterisk to be able to accept inbound video connections and setup an extension to record as follows:
`pjsip.conf` contains:

```
[video-trunk]
type = endpoint
transport = transport-tls-nat
force_rport = yes
ice_support = yes
direct_media = no
context = video
disallow = all
allow = h264,ulaw
```

`extensions.conf` contains:

```
[video]
exten = 2001,1,Verbose(1, "${CALLERID(num)} dialed in.")
 same = n,Answer()
 same = n,Wait(2)
 same = n,Record("/recording/file.wav",0,30,qf)
 same = n,Hangup()
```

I’m able to use Linphone to establish a connection to `2001@my-sip.example.com`, but when the Record gets triggered the console outputs:

```
[Sep 29 17:44:37] WARNING[6614][C-00000001]: file.c:1504 ast_writefile: No such format 'h264'
```

(repeatedly as long as I stay connected).

I’ve looked at `file.c` and the message comes after it traverses the `&formats` – adding debugging information to that function, I find that it doesn’t contain any video codecs… just:

```
wav16
wav
WAV|wav49
g722
au
alaw|al|alw
pcm|ulaw|ul|mu|ulw
gsm
```

Various things on the internet (more than a few years old now) said that the above should work.

Is there a way to record video on a current version of Asterisk? I’ve found a reference to `app_mp4` on the net, but it requires the `mpeg4ip` library which hasn’t been maintained for 14+ years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `modules.conf` I was missing:

```
load = format_h264.so
```

Once I added that, it creates the files (although still having issues playing them back using Playback, but that wasn't my initial question)